# Responses tab difficult to read on meta.photo.SE

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The highlighted entries on the user responses tab is barely readable (white text on pale yellow background) on meta.photo.SE

[image]

Comment: screenshot? just so we're clear

Comment: @JeffAtwood Would love to, but I don't have any responses, nor can I upload to imgurl from my current host. Theoretically though, you should now have a response, so should be able to go to http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/users/94/jeffs-atwood?tab=responses and see the issue yourself.

Comment: aha indeed! I'll update it.

Comment: i'm fixing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now fixed, with a olive coloured background.

Comment: Answer added so that this no longer shows as "unanswered", especially as it's [status-completed].